# Using couchdb to display views grouping

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have multiple documents stored that look like this and I want to aggregate the records, appts and calls into a view.

```
{
    "_id": "1010997127",
    "_rev": "1-a570c157b140839b4214569b831a8791",
    "value": {
        "rev": "1-a570c157b140839b4214569b831a8791"
    },
    "key": "1010997127",
    "doc": {
        "_id": "1010997127",
        "_rev": "1-a570c157b140839b4214569b831a8791",
        "appted": "no",
        "called": "yes",
        "user": "user1"
    }
}

... more ...
```

I want my view output to look like this.

```
{
    rows: [
        {
            user: "user1",
            records: 280,
            called: 22,
            appted: 11
        },
        {
            user: "user2",
            records: 34,
            called: 33,
            appted: 22
        },
        {
            user: "user3",
            records: 291,
            called: 44,
            appted: 33
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this or a version of this possible using couchdb views?

In the map function I did this and reduced it using  `_count`

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.user, doc.called);
}
```

and the output does not count the calls?

```
{
    rows: [
        {
            key: "user1",
            value: 280
        },
        {
            key: "user2",
            value: 34
        },
        {
            key: "user3",
            value: 291
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you supply more input examples?  Not sure what you want to do with records, called, appted.  How do you want to count those?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the reply, I ended up swapping to mongodb as they have a very easy aggregation method and the rev id that couchdb offers is not critical for my use case, I really appreciate the interest though.